# How to structure Python code to support multiple releases of MY project (i.e. not multiple versions of Python)

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm working on the back end of a web-based system.  My code will receive calls from our web site and perform the actions requested by the user.  We would like to support multiple versions of our front end simultaneously.  So, for example, I might receive a request from V1 of our front end or from V2 of it.  I need to respond to either of these calls.

As you might expect, a lot of my code will be the same across versions.  For example, my function *get_list_access_params()*  will probably appear in both V1 and V2 (although there may be some changes to the code in it).  My listener should grab the request, figure out which version of our system the call came from and, then, call the right version of *get_list_access_params()*.

My hope is to not have to duplicate and rename the function as v1_get... and v2_get... but, rather, to duplicate the function in two code files, a v1 file and a v2 file.

This must be a common need but I can't figure out where to look for the answer.  Does anyone have a quick answer or can you direct me to a simple place to find it (I am a Python novice, BTW)?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your subprocess offers an API to the web sites.

The trick is to make it so that API v2 of the subprocess code can handle calls from both v1 and v2 web sites. This is called backward compatibility.

Also, it's nice if the v1 web site is not too picky about the data it receives and can for instance handle a v2 answer from the subprocess that has more information than it used to have in v1. This is called forward compatibility. Json and xml are good ways to achieve it, since you can add properties and attributes at will without harming the parsing of the old properties.

So the solution, I think, does not lie in a python trick, but in careful design of the API of your subprocess such that the API will not break as the subprocess's functionality increases.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is a pretty normal problem with a straight-forward solution. **The solution is on a higher level than within your Python code**. You probably have some kind of front-end exposed to the internet that receives and processes requests. Some of these requests are forwarded to your Python-based back-end, others are denied, others are answered directly by the front-end. Such a front-end is usually also used to perform load-balancing by forwarding requests to multiple back-end servers in some "intelligent" fashion. These days, nginx is often used for this. If you do not have a front-end like this, you should deploy one. But from "My code will receive calls from our web site" I guess you have an entity that processes requests before they arrive at your Python application.

The solution to your problem is to deploy different versions of your Python-based back-end. Just run different "servers" for your different code versions. Then, it's up to the front-end to decide which request is forwarded to which back-end, based on e.g. simple URL parsing.

Example:

```
http://application.com/submit_data?v=1
```

will be parsed by your front-end. It sees `v=1` and knows that this request should be passed to the back-end server listening at e.g. `localhost:3000`.

A different request, such as

```
http://application.com/submit_data?v=2
```

is configured to be forwarded to e.g. `localhost:3001`, an entirely independent instance of your Python back-end.

Comment: If I read the question right, it's the web site's code that calls his python subprocess.

Comment: Yes, but implementing different "code versions" within one code revision is just dirty. One *can* separate different code versions on a higher level, and this is what should be done. "We would like to support multiple versions of our front end simultaneously" -- One could consider this subprocess code being part of the front-end. If they deploy different front-end versions, the problem is solved by definition.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of tricks - they basically reply on discipline on the development teams part:

1. Publish an API and **stick to it** all V2 functions of the same name **must** accept the same parameters and return compatible results when so called.
2. Have a general interface say `fred` that just wraps your V1 functions
3. Make use of named and defaulted parameters rather than positional parameters, then if your version 2 code supports some additional parameters but the defaults result in the version 1 behaviour you will be golden.
4. **Use Namespaces**
5. If you define your functions in the `fn(*arg, **agv)` format you can have a wrapper in your general interface that works out if the V1 or V2 functions are intended in a given call.
6. You can have an optional parameter `ifversion=1` in all your functions that might be ambiguous and use it when you specifically need the version 2 stuff.

There is another really simple method which is for the V2 front end to connect to a different port or use a specific flag in the html requrest.